# if else - php display based on css value ? is posibol?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display a `div` based on `li` with `class=active`, so that if the `li` does not have `class` as `active`, the `div` should be hidden.

Here is my code (I have commented the code where I need to display/hide the div)

```
    @if ( ! $links->isEmpty())
        <div id="videos">
                <table class="table table-striped links-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="name">{{ trans('stream::main.name') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ trans('stream::main.quality') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ trans('stream::main.report') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ trans('stream::main.added') }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                @foreach ($links as $k => $video)             
                        @if((int)$video->approved)


                            <li {{ $k === 0 ? 'class="active"' : null }} id="{{$video->id}}" style="list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;">
                            <table class="table table-striped links-table"><tr>
                                <td class="name hover">
                                <a href="#" data-bind="click: renderTab.bind($data, {{(int)$video->id}}, '{{$video->url}}', '{{$video->type}}', 500)">
                                    <img data-bind="attr: {src: app.utils.getFavicon('{{$video->url}}')}"> {{ $video->label }}</a></td>
                                <td style="width:110px;">{{$video->quality}}</td>
                                <td style="width:110px;"><i class="fa fa-warning text-primary"></i> <a href="#" data-bind="click: report.bind($data, '{{$video->id}}')">{{ trans('stream::main.report') }}</a></td>
                                <td style="width:110px;">{{$video->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                            </tr></table>
                            </li>
//------DOWN IS THE DIV, AND NEED TO DISPLAY JUST IF THE CLASS IS ACTIVE-------------
                            <div class="tab-content"></div>
//-------------------
                        @endif             
                @endforeach

            </ul>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

        <video id="trailer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="500px"> </video>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not do this.

```
@if($k === 0)
<div class="tab-content"></div>
@endif
```

or

```
<div {{ $k === 0 ? 'style="display:none"' : '' }} class="tab-content"></div>
```

**Update**

what would i do in your case is something like this.

in your li add a class.

```
    <li class="video_content" id="{{$video->id}}" 
             style="list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;">
```

then i put the div inside the list. right now if you inspect the list it's not rendering correctly.

```
<li class="video_content" id="{{$video->id}}" 
                 style="list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;">
   //CONTENTS
   <div {{ $k === 0 ? 'style="display:none"' : '' }} class="tab-content"></div>
</li>
```

then i'll add a jquery script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.video_content').click(function(){
       $(this).find('tab-content').show();
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi dakine, this codes dont work for me, but i see you use laravel, and maybe you can help me to find the solution, in order to do this, here are FULL php, js and css: http://seriespepe.tv/new/tests/php.txt - http://seriespepe.tv/new/tests/js.txt - http://seriespepe.tv/new/tests/css.txt - And this is the test page - http://seriespepe.tv/new/series-online/2-beach-heat-miami/seasons/1/episodes/2

Comment: from my understanding is that you want to hide the div if li class is not active. which is generated based on a condition if $k === 0 which $k is an index of an array. my suggestion was to use the condition $k === 0 to hide or display the div since it's the same thing. so why does this code doesn't work.  is there other things to be considered.

Comment: now i use your first code, and if you check http://seriespepe.tv/new/series-online/2-beach-heat-miami/seasons/1/episodes/2 - you can see... all players are open under the first li (111) - to check, please click on 222, 333,....

Comment: of corse, first li (111) is active on load, but if you make click on second li (222), this second li is "active" and first li dont have any class. I need to have the player (div class="tab-content") down, on the active li

Comment: so what you want to accomplish is that the first item show the div then the remaining items have div's that are hidden. then you want to click the item to show the div. is that what you're trying to accomplish. if so. you need some query to accomplish the task. confirm if my assessment is correct and i'll show you how to do it with jquery.

Comment: YES - THIS IS CORRECT

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `PHP` react to classes; it should be the other way around, PHP determining what classes things have, as it is generating the HTML. This can be done with CSS only: hide the elements you want hidden, set them to visible when they get the class you intend. An easy sample:

```css
.invisible-when-inactive {
  display: none;
}
.invisible-when-inactive.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Normal div
</div>
<div class="invisible-when-inactive">
  Hidden div 1
</div>
<div class="invisible-when-inactive active">
  Active hidden div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amadan's CSS approach works well if you're looking to avoid writing JavaScript, but in case it's an option, you can use the ID on the `li` to check if it has a class on it:

```
if ($('#idOfListItem').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#idOfDiv').show();
} else {
    $('#idOfDiv').hide();
}
```

You'll need to assign an ID (or classes that work together) to the `div` associated with the `li` in order to do show and hide with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be done with PHP. It should be done with CSS. Make sure to add them to your css document in the exact order listed

**Hidden State**

```
.tab-content {
   display: none;
}
```

**Active State**

```
li.active + .tab-content {
   display: block;
}
```